# Snow Leopard iSCSI initiator

Tags: iscsi, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx-server

I'm getting ready for a large Snow Leopard migration and am having problems with the standard iSCSI initiator from globalSAN. After some research I found out that the initiator is just incompatible with Snow Leopard. My question is what iSCSI initiator are you using on your Mac OS X Server Box, please only answer if you are using Snow Leopard, I've already tried most iSCSI initiators for plain old Leopard.

Thank You.

Comment: Note: The globalSAN initiator works with Snow Leopard so long as you boot the computer into 32bit mode. Use `sudo nvram boot-args="arch=i386"` to accomplish this.

Comment: Would save others a lot of time if you list what you have tried here. I, for one, use globalSAN in 32bit mode.

Comment: I use globalSan in 32bit mode as well. To be honest, it's the only one I could find other than the ATTO one, but it costs $$

Answer (score 2):

They only one that works right now is the ATTO Xtend SAN initiator... rock solid and supported with 64 bit... they created a new release to support snow leopard!

Comment: How much did you pay for it?

Answer (score 0):

Or Compile open-Iscsi. not user friendly though